# How to install oracle11gr2 on ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: ubuntu, oracle-database

I am working with this [tutorial](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/04/17/how-to-install-oracle-11g-r2-database-on-ubuntu-15-04-vivid-64bit-gnulinux-easy-guide/).
But i got this error on step 5:

```
Package libtiff4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'libtiff4' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libtiff4-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libpthread-stubs0
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing libtiff4 from another source is not possible, because it conflicts with libtiff5.

You can try to build a dummy package with equivs to fulfill the dependency:

```
apt-get install equivs
equivs-control libtiff4-dev
```

Edit the control file to give it a version bigger than 4.0.3.

```
equivs-build libtiff4-dev
```

and install the package.

Comment: with this command:
equivs-build libtiff4-dev
I got this:

dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_prep
sh: 1: cannot open package: No such file
sh: 1: defaults: not found
dh_prep: rm -f debian/<package name; defaults to equivs-dummy>.*.debhelper returned exit code 127
debian/rules:13: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 25
Error in the build process: exit status 2

Comment: hello !!!!
root@nouha-VPCEH16EF:/home/nouha# equivs-build libtiff4-dev
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_prep
sh: 1: cannot open package: No such file
sh: 1: defaults: not found
dh_prep: rm -f debian/<package name; defaults to equivs-dummy>.*.debhelper returned exit code 127
debian/rules:13: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 25
Error in the build process: exit status 2

Answer (score -1):

the latest version of ubuntu is not support the oracle:

[How to install Oracle 11 Release 2 on ubuntu 15.04?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3746197)

> Ubuntu is not a supported platform. I wrote a few howto's in the past,
>   for example, Install Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu Linux 11.04 (64-bit)
>   Howto, but since 11.10 there have been too many changes that will
>   complicate the installation, like Ubuntu 12.04 Oracle XE and
>   ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported. It's not really worth it
>   anymore.
>
> If you want to install Oracle database 11g I recommend you
>   install Oracle Linux 5, which is free and runs fine under VirtualBox.
>   The later will most likely be necessary if your computer is a laptop
>   or desktop system, since Oracle Linux is made for server hardware.